# error getting chaincode code mycc: path to chaincode does not exist

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm doing this tutorial: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html

Now I am on my Peer and want to Install & Instantiate Chaincode.

For this I am doing:

```
root@23096337731b:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/
```

But then I get this output:

```
2019-01-31 08:01:44.988 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2019-01-31 08:01:44.988 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: error getting chaincode code mycc: path to chaincode does not exist: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go
```

**Update:**

I think it's because I'm doing this:

```
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/
```

And the compiler thinks that the github link is a local directory.

Comment: check if chaincode is present in /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/chaincode/ by logging to cli container

Answer (score 4):

The key point is the place where you put the chaincode must be mounted exactly.

In the tutorial source code, when you read the file `docker-compose-cli.yaml`, you will see this line

```
volumes
    - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
```

`./../chaincode` is the path to the chaincode folder

One more thing, if you choose golang for the chaincode, the path when you call `install chaincode` will be shorter ([read more](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#install-instantiate-chaincode)):

```
# this installs the Go chaincode. For go chaincode -p takes the relative path from $GOPATH/src
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/
```

Node.js version:

```
# this installs the Node.js chaincode
# make note of the -l flag to indicate "node" chaincode
# for node chaincode -p takes the absolute path to the node.js chaincode
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -l node -p /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/chaincode/chaincode_example02/node/
```

Comment: as per docker-compose.yml file a new empty folder(s) called chaincode and script will be created in directory just above your project folder. Copy the chaincode file(.go) from fabric samples and paste it there, make sure to create folder(s) if you have appended anything after '/chaincode' as a path and also copy right chaincode because you will be quering it later.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check if the chaincode is on that folder. Also the path for a go chaincode has to be relative to the gopath.

Comment: you can log into the cli container by doing `docker exec -it cli bash` after that you can see if you have there the chaincode.